# Importance of preprocessing in NLP

Tags: natural-language

I have implemented a CNN model on text data for classification. The  performance of model without preprocessing is better than model with preprocessing. The variation of the performance is  nearly 3%

What can we infer from this. Can we consider the model without preprocessing. Is it meaningful?

Any kind reference is also helpful

Comment: Preprocessing may harm in some cases.  You should describe (a) what NLP problem you are working on (b) what is your performance measurement (c) what preprocessing you conducted.

Comment: I have considered a binary classification problem with accuracy as measurement and followed basic preprocessing techniques like removal of stop words,punctuations , non ascii characters, lower case but the model without these preprocessing techniques i working better

Comment: @KotaMori I what way preprocessing is harmful

Comment: Some applications extract important information from stop words and punctuations. An example would be author identification. Since authors may have styles on the choice of stop words and frequencies of punctuations, removing them can discard useful information from data.

Comment: So we can have models without preprocessing if it performs better

Comment: You can have whatever model you want. It just may not be useful in the way you intend. As a case study on the effects of preprocessing, you may enjoy reading [ner and pos when nothing is capitalized](https://aclanthology.org/D19-1650).